# NodeJS & Python; characters not escaping

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, mkdir, unc

I have a NodeJS project that I'm having call a Python script which simply makes a new directory in a remote file storing network (a UNC path).

However, when I try to use `os.mkdir` in the Python, it seems that on the server-side, the Node doesn't want to escape the '\' characters, meaning it's trying to create a directory `"\\\\myserver.com\\folder1\\newFolder"` instead of `"\\myserver.com\folder1\newFolder"`

**Code:**

*NodeJS:*

```
var pyshell = new PythonShell('mkdir.py', {scriptPath:"/path/toScript"});   //Calls python script (works well)
```

*Python:*

```
import os
import sys
print("SCRIPT CALLED")    #Test that .py file is being called
os.mkdir("\\\\myserver.com\\folder1\\newFolder")
```

*Output (on server):*

```
SCRIPT CALLED      #Shows script is being called properly, as print method is showing
Error: OSError: [Errno 71] Protocol error: '\\\\myserver.com\\folder1\\newFolder'
File "/home/mkdir.py", line 8, in <module>
      os.mkdir("\\\\myserver.com\\folder1\\newFolder")
```

My best guess here based on the error is that it's not escaping the characters when trying to make the directory. Any insight? I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: That can't be your exact code, because what you're saying is impossible.  Are you actually hard-coding a path in your Python file?  Or are you passing it from node.js?  Escape characters are only meaningful for hard-coded paths.  If you're passing the path from node.js, then don't double the backslashes.  Send the exact string you want.

Comment: Did you confirm that the `os.mkdir` script works to create a folder via UNC when called natively from Python (removing Node.js from the picture as it's almost certainly irrelevant)?

Comment: Also remember that ALL Windows APIs accept forward slashes as well.  You can skip the escaping and send forward slashes.

Comment: @TimRoberts I will eventually be passing in a path from Node but for the time being I was trying to hard code the path just to see if it's even possible. And after trying the  forward slashes I get a `No such file or directory` error

Comment: @jarmod Yes I just created a new .py file on my desktop with no supporting code and copied the code from above into it. It made the directory in the file share network no problem.

Comment: You might investigate at [extrabacon/python-shell](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell) if that's what you're using. It may be parsing the Python script instead of simply executing the Python script using native Python.

Comment: Are you creating that script on the fly, or is it stored in a known location?  The error message says it occurred on line 8, so that can't be the exact contents of your file.

Comment: @TimRoberts the script is in the same directory as the .js file. And line 8 is correct; it's a 10 line python script and the `mkdir()` command is on line 8, which I'm guessing is throwing the error because it's trying to `os.mkdir()` the literal string with excess '\' 's and not escaping them, making it an invalid dir format

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but Python simply does not work that way.  Could you possibly have an "r" before the string?

Comment: @TimRoberts exactly which is why this really throwing me off, but I have had some similar issues with NodeJS and slashes before (circa another issue I was having: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66250918/12060361). I made sure it's not a raw string and I even tried doing a raw string with single slashes to no avail